# Prevent create a record if error in observer Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How I can block create a record on a model if function gives me an error?

I have Observer:

```
public function created(Post $post)
{
    Auth::guest() ? $post->sendEmailNotification($post->guest_token) : '';
}
```

I need: if `sendEmailNotification` get an exception, then not create the record. Now, if I get an exception, post whatever creating.

Comment: add try catch block , and return ' ' in catch in sendEmailNotification

Answer (score 2):

You have to use creating instead of created, creating is fired before the creation so just catch the exception and return false :

```
public function creating(Post $post)
{
    try {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            $post->sendEmailNotification($post->guest_token);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```